# Why does my 'where in' Doctrine DQL query not return expected results?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql, where-in

I have the following DQL query:

```
$queries_query = $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT q FROM \Entities\Query q INNER JOIN q.store s WHERE s.tvRegionId IN (?1)');
$queries_query->setParameter(1, $tv_region_ids);
```

It only returns results that match the first value in the where clause. The variable $tv_region_ids contains comma separated values. If I change that variable to an array I get the following message:

Notice: Array to string conversion

Can anyone shed some light on my problem please. I am completely stumped.

Comment: `DQL`? never heard of it :P

Comment: What does `$tv_region_ids` look like?

Comment: string(38) "16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1"

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass a string into DQL for a `IN` type query. You need to pass in an array. Because DQL works very much like prepared statements, an `IN` query is treated as an expression and raw data must be provided into the `setParameter` function.

**Example**

```
$tv_region_ids = [16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1];

$queries_query = $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT q FROM \Entities\Query q INNER JOIN q.store s WHERE s.tvRegionId IN (?1)');
$queries_query->setParameter(1, $tv_region_ids);
```

**Converting your String (Just Incase)**

```
$string = "16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1";

$tv_regions_ids = explode(",", $string);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but as mentioned in my question, changing the $tv_region_ids to an array results in the following error: Notice: Array to string conversion in ...library/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php on line 574